# Swift code in Object-C: No visible @interface for 'ClassName' declares the selector 'alloc'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use a swift class inside Objective-C code.

```
 ThisClass *thisClass = [[ThisClass alloc] init];
```

However, when trying to allocate and initialize that class, I get this error:

> No visible @interface for 'ThisClass' declares the selector 'alloc'

Class is declared as such in the Swift file:

```
@objc class ThisClass : NSObject {
```

The class inherits from NSObject, so I don't know what its problem is.

Here is my class inside my ProjectName-swift.h:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC21ProductName16ClassName")
@interface ThisClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray<Presentation *> * __nonnull presentations;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray<Presentation *> * __nonnull userPresentations;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache * __nonnull imageCache;
- (UIImage * __nullable)imageForPresentationSlideWithPresentation:(Presentation * __nonnull)presentation slideNumber:(NSInteger)slideNumber;
- (UIImage * __nullable)thumbnailForPresentationSlideWithPresentation:(Presentation * __nonnull)presentation slideNumber:(NSInteger)slideNumber;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it - trying to keep the real source code private

Comment: That makes sense, but I have this at the top: #import "ProjectName-swift.h"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93426/discussion-between-etayluz-and-matt).

Comment: Nailed it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your *real* code (as opposed to what you are showing *here*) you have capitalized the name of your variable `PresentationData`. But this is already the name of the class. That sort of thing drives the compiler nuts (and is not good for readers of your code either - variable names should always start with a small letter).

Comment: That is the dumbest thing in the world! Thank you so much :) You're a genius, Matt!

Comment: I knew you'd like it! :)